# ids of elements of externally loaded svg file

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I have loaded an svg file into a "g" as this (canvas is Snap-svg based):

```
var _i = new Image();
_i.src = 'svgFile.svg';
$(_i).load(function () {
    Snap.load(src, function(f){
    _imagen = canvas.g(f.select('*'));
    canvas.append(_imagen);
    });
```

The svg file (svgFile.svg) contains (among other things):

```
<path id="letterN" fill="#FCEA0D" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M606,538 ... z"/>
```

The external file is appended fine and I can see it in the page. But when I look up the element (path) in the console, I see it has id = "Shyphnh2b1fg". This happens to all svg elements in the file. Why did the ids change? And more importantly, how can it be avoided? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually isn't the SVG id, so I suspect you are looking at the wrong thing.

Snap adds its own id, if you look at something like the Chrome Console log, and do a console.log( someElement ), you will see that the object will have an id, but the underlying SVG element (accessible via someElement.attr, or someElement.node), will then show the actual SVG, click on 'attributes', and you will see 'id' has the original there.

So basically, you are looking at the Snap instance Id, and not the svg element Id which are separate things. The following should help a bit

```
console.log( el );
console.log( el.id ); // snap id, don't often need to use this
console.log( el.attr('id') ); // use this normally, snap access to underlying svg id
console.log( el.node.attributes.id.value ); // actual reference to svg id, should be the same as attr('id')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ian. For others who might arrive here: Snap.select('#letterN') will give you access to the element.